# Angular2 RC6 - importing BrowserModule in my submodules

Tags: angular

I have `DashboardModule` imported in my root `AppModule`. In a component template from `DashboardModule` I use `*ngFor`. It is declared in `BrowserModule` (precisely in `CommonModule` imported by `BrowserModule`).

I'd like to declare importing of `BrowserModule` once in my application in root module. But something is not working and I must import it also in `DashboardModule`. When I comment out importing, I have error in console `Can't bind to 'ngForOf' since it isn't a known property of ...`.

Here is the plunker, currently working: http://plnkr.co/edit/73SYTnsMJxoVl5OSvWiF?p=preview (best view in Chrome because of console usage).

Edit file `src/dashboard/dashboard.module.ts` - comment line 18 (importing BrowserModule) and error is visible in console.

Comment: You shouldn't import `BrowserModule` in your submodules. Instead, you should import `CommonModule`. `CommonModule` contributes the common directives such as `ngIf` or `ngFor`. `BrowserModule` imports `CommonModule` and then re-exports it and that's the reason you are able to use `ngFor` in your root module.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should **not** import `BrowserModule` in submodule.

Import `BrowserModule` in the root module and `CommonModule` in submodules.

[**Plunker example**](http://plnkr.co/edit/bO83VGBfy7M9yn57SXBj?p=preview)

See also https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/cookbook/ngmodule-faq.html#q-browser-vs-common-module

> Do not import `BrowserModule` in any other module. Feature modules and lazy loaded modules should import `CommonModule` instead. They need the common directives. They don't need to re-install the app-wide providers.

Answer (score 1):

Per the documentation for NgModules, it says to import the BrowserModule in the root module and CommonModule in feature modules.