# Angular2 RC6 Parent Child Components

Tags: angular

I've looked at the other Angular2 RC6 parent child posts but none of them solve the issue I am having.

I've got my main AppModule that imports a HomeModule.  That seems to work.  Now I've added a MapModule that implements angular2-google-maps as an import into my HomeModule and I am getting the error:

```
'google-map' is not a known element:
1. If 'google-map' is an Angular component, then verify that it is part of this module.
2. If 'google-map' is a Web Component then add "CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA" to the '@NgModule.schema' of this component to suppress this message. ("<h1>home</h1>[ERROR ->]<google-map></google-map>"): HomeComponent@0:13
```

Here is my setup:

```
// ----------
// AppModule
// ----------
@NgModule({
    imports: [
        BrowserModule,
        FormsModule,
        ReactiveFormsModule,
        HttpModule,
        HomeModule,
        routing
    ],
    declarations: [
        AppComponent,
    ],
    // schemas: [CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA],
    providers: [
        {provide: APP_BASE_HREF, useValue : '/' },
        {provide: LocationStrategy, useClass: HashLocationStrategy}
    ],
    bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule {}

// ----------
// HomeModule
// ----------
@NgModule({
    imports: [
        BrowserModule,
        FormsModule,
        ReactiveFormsModule,
        HttpModule,
        MapModule,
    ],
    declarations: [
        HomeComponent
    ],
    bootstrap: [HomeComponent]
})
export class HomeModule {}

// ----------
// HomeComponent
// ----------
@Component({
    selector: 'home',
    template: "<h1>home</h1><google-map></google-map>",
    styleUrls: ['home.scss'],
})
export class HomeComponent {}

// ----------
// MapModule
// ----------
@NgModule({
    imports: [
        BrowserModule,
        CommonModule,
        FormsModule,
        AgmCoreModule.forRoot({
            apiKey: '<my-api-key>'
        })
    ],
    declarations: [MapComponent],
    providers: [MapService],
    bootstrap: [MapComponent]
})
export class MapModule {}

// ----------
// Map Component
// ----------
@Component({
    selector: 'google-map',
    templateUrl: 'map.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['map.scss']
})
export class MapComponent {}
```

adding CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA to the module get's rid of the error but the map doesn't render.

If I make the MapModule part of the AppModule directly instead of as a child to the HomeModule then I see the map.

Any clues?

---

****Edit****

---

Thanks for the comments so far. My code looks cleaner now.  I've applied the following changes based on comments but the error remains the same.  My new code looks like the following.

```
// ----------
// AppModule
// ----------
@NgModule({
    imports: [
        BrowserModule,
        FormsModule,
        ReactiveFormsModule,
        HttpModule,
        HomeModule,
        routing
    ],
    declarations: [
        AppComponent,
    ],
    // schemas: [CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA],
    providers: [
        {provide: APP_BASE_HREF, useValue : '/' },
        {provide: LocationStrategy, useClass: HashLocationStrategy}
    ],
    bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule {}

// ----------
// HomeModule
// ----------
@NgModule({
    imports: [
        CommonModule,
        MapModule,
    ],
    declarations: [
        HomeComponent
    ]
})
export class HomeModule {}

// ----------
// HomeComponent
// ----------
@Component({
    selector: 'home',
    template: "<h1>home</h1><google-map></google-map>",
    styleUrls: ['home.scss'],
})
export class HomeComponent {}

// ----------
// MapModule
// ----------
@NgModule({
    imports: [
        CommonModule,
        AgmCoreModule.forRoot({
            apiKey: '<my-api-key>'
        })
    ],
    declarations: [MapComponent],
    providers: [MapService]
})
export class MapModule {}

// ----------
// Map Component
// ----------
@Component({
    selector: 'google-map',
    templateUrl: 'map.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['map.scss']
})
export class MapComponent {}
```

Additionally I checked out the link provided to the other Stack Overflow issue and I noticed they had a parent-child example but in their example the child did not have a module tied to it.  The MapComponent in my example is pretty complex with ties to the angular2-google-map module and seems like it should have it's own module to handle that.

---

** Edit 2 **

---

I've added a plunker post to replicate my problem.
http://plnkr.co/edit/7M71N6ttYR2s9yNdB3UT?p=preview

Comment: Note that only the `app.module` should import `BrowserModule` and have a `bootstrap` property. Can you remove those from the modules and see if that helped? Also, no need for duplicate imports of `FormsModule` and `HttpModule` and `ReactiveFormsModule`. It's suffice that the `app.module` imports them.

Comment: To extend on @mrgoos hint, other modules should import `CommonModule` instead of `BrowserModule` (`BrowserModule` exports `CommonModule`, therefore if you import `BrowserModule` you don't need to add `CommonModule` again).

Comment: True. Like he did in `MapModule`.

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39414231/angular2-rc6-importing-browsermodule-in-my-submodules/39414253#39414253

Comment: I've cleaned up my code and posted it as an edit.  My code looks cleaner but the error still remains.

Comment: @yurzui the stackoverflow link provided has a nice plunker example with a parent-child example but the child in the example doesn't have a module where I am dealing with a child that is managed by a module.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution to my issue.  I needed to add the exports to my MapModule so that other components could use the component.  My final change was to MapModule as follows

```
// ----------
// MapModule
// ----------
@NgModule({
    imports: [
        CommonModule,
        AgmCoreModule.forRoot({
            apiKey: '<my-api-key>'
        })
    ],
    declarations: [MapComponent],
    exports: [MapComponent],
    providers: [MapService]
})
export class MapModule {}
```

**exports: [MapComponent]**

Comment: ahhh yeah. you need it to make this component "public". kk.

Answer (score 1):

Note that only the `app.module` should import `BrowserModule` and have a `bootstrap` property. Can you remove those from the modules and see if that helped? Keep importing `CommonModule` as you did in your `MapModule` for all non `app.module` modules.

Also, no need for duplicate imports of `FormsModule`, `HttpModule` and `ReactiveFormsModule`. It's suffice that the `app.module` imports them.

p.s. sorry for commenting and then answering, I have a strange bug in chrome in the answer box that for some reason causes the header pane to duplicate itself over the box :(

[image]